# Hibernate cannot execute query that executes fine from terminal

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot project (on linux) and a simple database that consists out of two entities - sayings and tags. Saying can have multiple tags, and each tag can be used to tag multiple sayings, so it's many to many relationship. Table `saying_tags` is used to connect sayings and tags using their ids.

When I try to select all sayings that have exactly specified tags using this query, and that query selects something (result is not empty), hibernate throws exception saying `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.` but column `id` doesn't even exist in this query. When I try to execute it from terminal or DBeaver it works fine, and returns me what I expect.

I even tried to hardcode the query with exact parameters to be sure that hibernate is not changing anything in the query, and it still fails. And I literally copy the query when hibernate logs it to console and it works fine in terminal.

This is the query with hard-coded values and the method inside an interface extending `JpaRepository<Saying, Long>` that executes it:

```
@Query(value="select saying_id from saying_tags group by saying_id having count(distinct case when tags_id in (33) then tags_id else 0 end) = 1 and min(case when tags_id in (33) then tags_id else 0 end) > 0", nativeQuery=true)
public List<Saying> getSayingsContainingExactlyGivenTags();
```

Comment: How are you executing this query with Hibernate.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have an interface extending JpaRepository<Saying, Long>, and a method with `@Query(value="query" , nativeQuery=true)`.

Comment: Please add that code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query projects a scalar value named `saying_id`, yet you are returning a `List` of `Saying` entities. Your projection should consist of all the properties from the `Saying` entity. You might also need `@SqlResultSetMapping` to make sure you map your result set to your entity correctly.